# Why did early satellites (e.g. China's Fanhui Shi Weixing) re-enter the atmosphere narrow end (nose)-first?

Tags: artificial-satellite, reentry

I was surprised to find out from @JohnnyRobinson's [new answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19799/12102) that China's series of [Fanhui Shi Weixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanhui_Shi_Weixing) spacecraft (FSW) used impregnated oak heat shields. I found this in [astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/f/fsw.html):

> The capsule for the FSW, **like that of the US Discoverer/KH-1 spy satellite**, was mounted heat shield-forward on top of the launch vehicle. The ablative impregnated-oak nose cap covered electrical equipment. The spherical aft dome contained the recovery parachute. (emphasis added)

**Question:** Did these spacecraft re-enter narrow-end or "nose" first? If so, was this aerodynamically stable? Most re-entry spacecraft (manned capsules for example) tend to be larger, blunt-end first. Why would nose-first have been chosen early-on?

---

[image]

**above:** Labeled "JB-2" in [astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/f/fsw.html), presumably a FSW spacecraft.

[image]

**above:** "Recovery of FSW-17 photoreconnaissance satellite." From [astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/f/fsw.html).

[image]

**above:** Image of FSW-3 or FSW-4 from [globalsecurity.org](http://www.globalsecurity.org/space/world/china/fsw-3.htm).

[image]

**above:** "FSW reconnaissance satellite in assembly." From [astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/f/fsw.html).

[image]

**above:** Screen shot from [China's Space Program - From Conception to Manned Spaceflight](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=XaqK7LOVsc0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Brian Harvey, 2004, Springer-Verlag London, 978-1-85233-566-3, (also [here](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781852335663))

[image]

**above:** Screen shot from [CORONA: America’s First Satellite Program](https://www.cia.gov/library/center-for-the-study-of-intelligence/csi-publications/books-and-monographs/corona.pdf) Kevin C. Ruffner, Ed., Center for the Study of Intelligence, Central Intelligence Agency, Washington, D-C. 1995

Comment: @OrganicMarble not sure what I was thinking re the original (sic) spelling, possibly a series of 21st century SF novellas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The advantages of the blunt end first design were known well before either vehicle was launched (1958, a few years earlier for spy satellite designers). However, pointy end first is the simplest design that works.

- Falling objects generally want to go heavy end first, draggy end last. With a heavy heat shield on the front and a light but bulky parachute in the back, pointy end first is more stable.
- Most rockets provide a cone shaped space for the payload. Launching blunt end first would need a large fairing, and putting the heat shield at the back makes connections to the rest of the spacecraft a whole lot more complicated.

That makes it perfect for early designs or when reliability is more important than launch mass. However, there are a couple of issues that make it impractical for large / manned capsules.

- It requires significantly more thermal shielding. Part of this is simple geometry - the blunt end has less area to cover. On top of that the shockwave from a blunt object keeps most of the heat away from the vehicle, so a blunt end first shield can be thinner as well.
- Acceleration and deceleration are in opposite directions. Equipment can be secured in all directions easily enough, but an astronaut would experience reentry as 8 g while tied to the ceiling, which seems distinctly unpleasant.

Comment: A very clear and well written answer as was [this one as well](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/19779/12102) - thanks!

Comment: Concerning "simple geometry - the blunt end has less area to cover".  Does not the "pointy end",  being at a slant, incur less air resistance (per area) than the blunt end?  I would think that would reduce some of the "pointy end" thermal shielding needs.  Do not both ends have the same sized air resistance profile - a circle.

Comment: @chux That part is assuming equal shield thickness. Although both ends do need to move the same volume of air, a sharp cone allows hot gases to flow along the surface of the vessel, increasing the thermal load.

Comment: Perhaps I'm ignorant here, but wouldn't experience the 8g of forces in a forward direction be safer than the current way during reentry? (8g of "backwards" acceleration)

The opposite being true during liftoff, obviously.  Seems they need swivel chairs.

Comment: @SarahBailey The forces are all in the same direction that the capsule is designed for - backwards deceleration during reentry is equivalent to forward acceleration during launch.

Comment: @QuentinClarkson Ah, I forgot that they'd feel the "push" in the opposite direction because of deceleration!  Thanks! :)