# White papers on alleged 1960s Chinese wooden ablative reentry heat shield

Tags: reentry, history, heat-shield

Popular sources, like Vintage Space and New Scientist, allege that the Chinese experimented with (oak?) wood ablative heat shields for manned reentry vehicles in the 1960s, but I have not been able to find any technical information.

Does anyone have translated English papers from the original project, or intelligence reports? Chinese documents would also be valuable, I would be willing to have them translated.

Comment: semi-unrelated: the primary active (ablative, as opposed to binder etc) component of SLA, the spray-on ablator used on the Shuttle tank and on Delta series rockets, is cork wood.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19799/12102), there are some [pix here too](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19804/12102). For a tl;dr, search for "oak" in here: http://www.astronautix.com/f/fsw.html and open this book in `books.google.com` and search for "oak": *China's Space Program - From Conception to Manned Spaceflight* Here is the book also: http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781852335663

Comment: Cork was used as part of the boost protection cover on Apollo, too

Answer (score 2):

Here is the wikipedia entry for the Chinese satellite.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanhui_Shi_Weixing