# Satellite Telemetry on the Internet

Tags: artificial-satellite, telemetry

Are there any web sites that show real time telemetry such as temps, bus voltages etc? Looking for one to follow.

Comment: It's a good question, I think a lot of the experimental cubesats will be transmitting their temperature, battery charge status, solar panel currents, etc. You might find something interesting looking at all links in [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24469/12102) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24471/12102) and https://satnogs.org/ and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32290/12102) and https://www.nanosats.eu/ and other cubesat compendia.

Comment: Hi https://satnogs.org team member here. We are working on visualizing some of the data we collect here: https://dashboard.satnogs.org **work in progress - things might brake**

Comment: Example on my previous comment: [Cubebel-1 dashboard](https://dashboard.satnogs.org/d/kMjaqI8mz/cubebel-1?refresh=1m&orgId=1)

Answer (score 3):

It's a very large satellite, but some live ISS telemetry is available at https://isslive.com/displays/index.html

(Theoretically anyway - it does not seem to be working at this writing)

User [uhoh](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/12102/uhoh) offered a different [link](http://www.telemetry.space/) for ISS telemetry - a much nicer format, IMHO - but it also does not seem to be working at this time.

Comment: you can add [this one](http://www.telemetry.space/) from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20358/12102)

Comment: That's a much nicer format, but it does not seem to be working either.

Comment: @uhoh seems more functional now :)!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn look more closely; https://i.stack.imgur.com/26UoT.png it hasn't been updated for almost 24 hours

Comment: Ahhh.. I expected "not working" to entail "no display" not "cached data"; good catch.

Comment: Both links mentioned in the answer draw their data from the same server, which stopped producing data during the government shutdown.  We're working our contacts to see if it can get brought back up, but folks just came back to work yesterday and likely have a number of higher priority tasks on their plate.

Comment: @OrganicMarble slightly related to your pending/upcoming capsule answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19808/12102