# Could we use the atmospheres of planets like Mars or Jupiter to separate xenon from them to replenish the engines?

Tags: mars, probe, jupiter

Could we use the atmospheres of planets like Mars or Jupiter to separate xenon from them to replenish the engines? I mean, touch the atmosphere of Mars and separate Argon and Xenon for ionic engines, would this be possible? Or the atmosphere would lower us?

Comment: Touching the atmosphere from an orbit would result in loosing orbital velocity by drag and entering to the denser lower parts of the atmosphere. Final a crash to the surface of Mars or a destruction by the high pressure of the gas giant Jupiter.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19771/is-atmospheric-skimming-for-propellant-feasible

Comment: @OrganicMarble Not a duplicate. The only thing there that addresses ion engines is HopDavid's "[But it's difficult to imagine...](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26607/12102)" Since the exhaust velocity of an ion engine is so much faster than the incident velocity of the atoms collected, you can conceivably gain more momentum than the resulting drag removes. That's not really covered well in answers there (except for that quote) so I think this needs a different answer.

Comment: However this might be a dupe of another question about collecting ion propulsion propellant from atmospheres, I don't know if there's one of those here or not. And of course, if you need the propellant *for a retrograde burn for orbit lowering* then the drag helps rather than hinders you.

Comment: Xenon is obtained from air liquifuyng. Xenon actually is byproduct, the main purpose is to obtain liquid oxygen and liquid nitrogen. The equpment is rather bulky and heavy. And xenon is very minor part of planets' atmospheres. So I think the mass of machinery would be prohibitively high for a spacecraft if compared with xenon extracted mass.

Comment: @Heopps if you have velocity available there are other, passive separation techniques *that might work* besides refrigeration. In a collection nozzle as density increases the light molecules will change their velocity distribution more quickly than the heavier, more ballistic atoms moving at the same speed. It's might be a niche field of aerodynamics and I don't know a lot about it. There are for example things called *aerodynamic lenses* but those are for actual aerosols and particulates; I don't know if there is anything analogous possible for atoms and molecules.

Comment: "_planets like mars or jupiter_"... those places are Quite Different, and the problems with resource extraction from one are likely to be somewhat different to resource extraction from the other. You might consider focussing your question a little more.

Comment: Shouldn't you verify the concentration of Xe before worrying about trying to retrieve it?  Which question are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if the physics of collecting ion propellant from atmospheres makes sense first. Using the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) and the [standard gravitational parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) for the two extreme cases that you've asked about, we can see what those orbital velocities might be for a circular orbit near the atmosphere (I'll use 5% larger than the planet's radius, it doesn't matter much for the speed calculation):

$$v^2 = GM \left( \frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a}\right)$$

```
planet     1.05 R        GM        v_circ      v_esc   
             m         m^3/s^2       m/s         m/s
Mars      3.56E+06    4.28E+13      3,500       4,900
Jupiter   7.34E+07    1.26E+17     42,000      59,000
```

The escape velocity is the speed at 1.05 $$ when you are just transitioning in a capture or release.

Now let's look at the velocities of ion engine exhaust. Assuming 100 kV acceleration voltage producing a kinetic energy E of 1E-04 GeV for a charge of +1, and using 1 GeV per nucleon for the masses and using $v/c = 2E/mc^2$

```
atom      mass      v/c          v
           GeV       -          m/s
helium       4     0.0071    2,100,000
argon       40     0.0022      670,000
xenon      131     0.0012      370,000
```

So even for the largest atom and the largest planet, the exhaust velocity at 100 kV is six times the orbital velocity.

This means that the available thrust can potentially be much larger than the drag you incur by dropping into the atmosphere and collecting it.

**However** that's if you use all the gas and don't try to separate a tiny amount of useful gas from the rest. If you are doing that you could certainly lose this advantage. For example if the concentration is only 1% then you'll need an exhaust velocity 100x larger than the orbital velocity just to break even!

So it's better to choose an ion engine design that can somehow work with the planet's native atmospheric mixture that occurs at the altitude where you're collecting it.

I have a hunch that this fraction problem has been explained in another answer on this site before, but I can't remember where.

Now, if you are *dropping into orbit*, then drag is your friend and it will work together with your thrust. For more on that see the [aerobraking](/questions/tagged/aerobraking) tag.

To lower your orbit after dropping into it, or to raise your orbit when it's time to go, or to just do a make-up burn to counteract drag and keep your current orbit, you'll do your burn somewhere near the lowest point.